# Charity Website - Is it possible to prepopulate input fields on Site B by submitting a form on Site A?

Tags: php, forms, url, submit, field

I am wondering if it's possible to have a user visit my website (Site A) and fill out a form that has first name, last name, email and a submit button. When the user hits submit, that information is emailed to me, but then the user is directed to this site https://my.charitywater.org/p/donate?campaign_id=34971#donation-info where there is a form that is asking for some of the same information.

I am wondering if any of that information that was gathered on my site (Site A) can be passed onto that Charity Water page and prepopulate those fields so that information does not have to be entered twice?

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a website (A) to cause a browser to go to another (arbitrary) site (B) and pre-fill form controls on B with data from A.

Site B would have to be explicitly designed to make that possible.

Comment: Aw really? I noticed the specific campaign is called from the campaign_id variable so I thought maybe the fields could be controlled by URL varialbes as well that were genereated from the Site A form :(

Comment: You are correct, and this is the only way to do it. Just know that they can change their site anytime and break yours. Not to mention that this is very rare that a site will work like this, most sites wont pre-populate fields based on get vars.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least if the website is one of your own you have some more tricks to play.

But I guess that is not the case so,

You might try to send the form for site (B) yourself. Look how the client side HTML/JavaScript sends the form and then try remaking that. Ask the visitor if he wants to participate on whatever its for and also send the data to site (B) if he wants to. 
When doing this you shut do it server side because browsers don't like crossing diffident domains in a request form your HTML/JavaScript.

Now you can even just get the result page of website (B) and show it to the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by passing the values to the third party site via GET variables.

Please note that while this currently works, it is not standard and completely depends on the third party site. It is entirely possible that they modify their code and break your site, in which there is no standard way of reimplementing this.

https://my.charitywater.org/p/donate?campaign_id=34971&payment_amt=100&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&comment_tx=This%20is%20my%20comment#donation-info